# Wordpress Javascript injection not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parent-child, parent

I created a js file in my child theme containing this code

```
    const prID = "10496";
const EL_prID = document.querySelector(`[data-product-id="${prID}"]`);

if (EL_prID) {
  EL_prID.parentNode.classList.add('is-hidden');}
```

I use a plugin to inject code in the header of my page: I added the url of my js file in the header.

I added the Css code:
.is-hidden:{display:none;}

When I check on the debugger the js file appears inside the header. But my html element is not hidden as it should.

Where is my mistake ? Should I add balise in my javascript file before and after the code ?

thank you

Comment: Is there any CSS overrding your rule?

Comment: The javascript is not even working...The class is-hidden is not added to my element...

Comment: You'll have to use @Damocles's solution or move your script to the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JS file is in the header, it means when it executes, the DOM of the page is not fully loaded. Wrap the stuff inside a load event listener (if you must do it in vanilla JS):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const prID = "10496";
  const EL_prID = document.querySelector(`[data-product-id="${prID}"]`);

  if (EL_prID) {
    EL_prID.parentNode.classList.add('is-hidden');
    // ...?
  }

});
```

This fires when all elements are loaded, thus, the query selector should at least find what it's supposed to (if the selector matches).

Comment: Another option would be to load the JS in the footer instead of header.